# How to understand Isaiah 44:1&2?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah, grammatical-historical

.

Isaiah 44:1 NASB

> But now listen, ***O Jacob, My servant***,
>   And Israel, whom I have chosen:

וְעַתָּה שְׁמַע, יַעֲקֹב עַבְדִּי; וְיִשְׂרָאֵל, בָּחַרְתִּי בוֹ. 
י

Isaiah 44:2 NASB

> Thus says the Lord who made you
>   And formed you from the womb, who will help you,
>   ‘Do not fear, ***O Jacob My servant*** And you Jeshurun whom I have chosen.

כֹּה-אָמַר יְהוָה עֹשֶׂךָ וְיֹצֶרְךָ מִבֶּטֶן, יַעְזְרֶךָּ:  אַל-תִּירָא ***עַבְדִּי יַעֲקֹב***, וִישֻׁרוּן בָּחַרְתִּי

The above texts have a similar phrase(O Jacob My servant) which somehow seems slightly different in Hebrew.I don't know much Hebrew grammar but would like to understand if there is any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Usally in a hebrew sentce the noun (Jacob) stands forward and the apposition (My servant) behind. So Jes 44,1a ist typicall (Jacob, my servant). Jes 44,2 (My servant, Jacob) is also possible. Its uncommon but there is no diffrent meaning. Perhabs there ist a emphesis of an untypicall construction, but not more.

You can have a look at Lettinga, J., Grammatik des biblischen Hebräisch, Leiden 2011, §71.

Comment: I would even say "less common" rather than "uncommon".